# How to get a MAX value from 3 columns in SQL Server stored procedures?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working on a project with C# and a SQL Server database. Right now I have to write a stored procedure, which needs to get a MAX value from 3 different columns.

My code looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetClass]
    @surname nvarchar(50),
    @maxClass int OUT
AS
    SELECT @maxClass = MAX 
    FROM (VALUES (Programming), (Mathematics), (Physics)) 
    FROM MissLess 
    WHERE Surname LIKE '%' + @surname + '%'
GO
```

I get an error for the second `FROM` and I'm not sure how to fix it.

The idea is to make it get the max value from those columns, when a surname is input. When no input is made(press enter) it just shows the max value from those 3 columns across all surnames.

Excuse me, if the formatting or the questions is not asked right, it's my first post here.

EDIT: made an error in @name, it's supposed to be @surname; and Name is supposed to be Surname.
EDIT FINAL: Thanks for the awesome help. I'm an ultra newbie in all of this, but it all seems like great fun. Was so close to just giving up, but decided to give this a shot. Thanks for all the answers!!!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you for that information. I'm just starting out, and the teacher will most likely get us informed about it. Thanks for the heads up on that.

Comment: Or if you are on Azure SQL database look at the `GREATEST` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to put these three values for the chosen row(s) into a table variable inside your stored procedure, in order to be able to apply the `MAX` to them.

Try something like this - I didn't know what **datatype** those values are - just assuming `INT` here, adapt as needed:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMaxValue]
    @surname NVARCHAR(50),
    @maxClass INT OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @IntTbl TABLE (AValue INT);
    
    INSERT INTO @IntTbl (AValue)
        SELECT Programming
        FROM MissLess 
        WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Mathematics
       FROM MissLess 
        WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Physics
        FROM MissLess 
        WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%';
        
    SELECT @maxClass = MAX(AValue)
    FROM @IntTbl;
GO
```

**Update** - ok, you *asked* for it ;-)

Since your search criteria *might* match multiple rows (at least you probably can't rule that out entirely), you'd have to first get the `MAX()` for each column, based on the search criteria:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMaxValue]
    @surname NVARCHAR(50),
    @maxClass INT OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @MaxMath INT, @MaxPhys INT, @MaxProgr INT;
    
    SELECT 
        @MaxMath = MAX(Mathematics),
        @MaxPhys = MAX(Physics),
        @MaxProgr = MAX(Programming)
    FROM 
        MissLess 
    WHERE 
        Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%';

    IF @MaxMath > @MaxPhys
    BEGIN       
        IF @MaxMath > @MaxProgr
            -- @MaxMath is bigger than both @MaxPhys AND @MaxProgr --> it's the overall MAX()
            SET @maxClass = @MaxMath;
        ELSE
            -- @MaxMath is bigger than @MaxPhys, but smaller than @MaxProgr 
            SET @maxClass = @MaxProgr;
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        IF @MaxPhys > @MaxProgr
            -- @MaxPhys is bigger than both @MaxMath AND @MaxProgr --> it's the overall MAX()
            SET @maxClass = @MaxPhys;
        ELSE
            -- @MaxPhys is bigger than @MaxMath, but smaller than @MaxProgr 
            SET @maxClass = @MaxProgr;
    END;

    SELECT @maxClass = MAX(AValue)
    FROM @IntTbl;
GO
```

**Update #2**: for a much nicer, cleaner solution for updating without using a table variable - see @AndrewCorrigan's answer further down, using a `CASE` expression.

Comment: Is it not possible to keep it all in the same table? And yes, all of those datatype values are INT

Comment: How would it look like with nested IF statements?

Comment: That update is absurd - a case statement is much simpler than those if blocks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=56db0cd8cc56f59b8af584bb2ea3b94d))

```
SELECT MAX(s) 
FROM MissLess      
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (Programming), (Mathematics), (Physics)) V(s)
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
```

If the `@name` predicate matches multiple rows you will have no indication of which row it came from though

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative solution using nested CASE statements:

```
SELECT @maxClass = MAX(CASE 
                             WHEN Programming >= Mathematics
                                  AND Programming >= Physics
                                      THEN Programming
                             WHEN Mathematics >= Physics
                                  AND Mathematics >= Programming
                                      THEN Mathematics
                             ELSE Physics
                       END)
FROM MissLess
WHERE Surname LIKE '%' + @surname + '%';
```